# Select rows of data frame with several values using logical operators

Tags: r, extract

I am using square brackets to select rows of data in a data frame based on logical operators. For example, if I have a data frame

```
df = data.frame(Letter = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 10), Number = rep(c(1:25), 4))
```

and I want to select rows that contain the letters A, B, or C I use the code

```
df = df[df$Letter == "A" | df$Letter == "B" | df$Letter == "C",]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to condense this, something along the lines of

```
df = df[df$Letter == c("A", "B", "C"),]
```

or maybe

```
df = df[df$Letter == "A" | "B" | "C",]
```

neither of which work, but basically I'm looking for a shorter, easier way to list several logical operators.

I would prefer to do it with square brackets rather than `subset()` or some other function but if it really isn't possible with square brackets then I would be open to other ideas

Comment: `df = df[df$Letter %in% c("A", "B", "C"),]` is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df <- df[df$Letter %in% c("A", "B", "C"),]
```

Answer (score 0):

For these instances I use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
new.df <- df %>% 
filter(Letter %in% c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I hope that helps,

cheers!

PS: dplyr cheat sheet is [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)